# jquery/ ajax callback doesn't fire twice without a page reload. Part 1

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, callback

I'm learning how to apply ajax to my jquery/php/mysql script for the purpose of callback firing. This question is probably from my ignorance when it come to the name of this term.

The Question: Is there a way to reset ajax callback without reloading the page script.

The Goal: I have a mysql query displaying on jQuery Accordian 1, 2, and 3. The goal is to click a query result href from Accordian and display the results in jQuery UI Tab 3 without a page reload...So far the script fires on my first callback but it doesn't fire a second time. Is there a term or jquery command that will reset jquery/ajax?

index.php

```
<?php 
...script... include'right.content.php';
?> 

<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
$("#submit").click(function(){   // when submitted 
  var name = $('#string2').val();
  var lname = $('#string3').val(); //  // POST name to php
  $('#stage').load('test.arena/test.php', {'string2':name, 'string3':lname,} ); 
});
$( "#tabs" ).tabs().find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ); 
$( "#accordion" ).accordion();
});
</script>
```

index.php - html section

```
   <div id="stage">
        <?php include'test.arena/test.php';?>
   </div>
```

right.content.php

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){      
  if($row['stats'] == "1"){
$data .= "<tr><td colspan='2'>".$row['order_number']."</td> 
<td colspan='2'>
<input type='hidden' id='string3' value='".$row['details']."'>
<input type='hidden' id='string2' value='".$row['order_number']."'>
<input type='button' id='submit' value='View'></td>
<td>info</td></tr>";
```

test.arena/test.php

```
if(!isset($_POST['string2'])){
$_POST['string2'] = "";

}else{

$string3 = "PO Number:" .$_POST['string3']; 
$string2 = "Order:" .$_POST['string2'];
echo $string3 ."</br>";
echo $string2 ."</br>";    
}
```

Comment: Let me know if more script is needed...my other pages are nothing but form ids and PHP scripts.

Comment: Is '#submit' inside of the '#stage' element?

Comment: Are the #string2 and #string3 inside a form? if so maybe add a return false at the bottom of the click fundtion. you may also want to try the live() function

Comment: Is #submit inside(a child of) #stage? If so, you need to re-bind the click event. That's actually easier than it sounds. Just use live('click',...) instead of click().

Comment: Crash, it's very unclear what you are asking here.

Comment: I went ahead and included a visual in [Part 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361405/jquery-ajax-callback-refire-without-a-page-reload-part-2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably because your submit button is inside of the 'stage' div. This means that when you load the new 'stage' content, it will delete the old button and add a new one and the new one won't have any click thing attached.

The quick fix for this is to use a 'live' handler.

```
$(function() {
  $("#submit").live('click', function(){   // when submitted 
        var name = $('#string2').val();
        var lname = $('#string3').val(); //  // POST name to php
        $('#stage').load('test.arena/test.php', {'string2':name, 'string3':lname,} );
  });

  $( "#tabs" ).tabs().find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ); 
  $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
});
```

But the other solution, which might make the problem clearer, is to re-add the click handler after the load finishes.

```
$(function() {

  function submitClicked() {
    var name = $('#string2').val();
    var lname = $('#string3').val(); //  // POST name to php
    $('#stage').load(
      'test.arena/test.php', 
      { 'string2':name, 'string3':lname },
      function() {
        addClickHandler();
      }
    ); // display results from test.php into #stage 
  }

  function addClickHandler() {
    $('#submit').click(submitClicked);
  }

  addClickHandler();
  $( "#tabs" ).tabs().find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ); 
  $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
});
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue...I will blame this on my php script. I'll put my ID submit inside the ID stage and try it again...thanks guys!

Answer (score 4):

Is the element with ID 'submit' inside the one with ID 'stage'? If so, try changing `$("#submit").click(function(){` to `$("#submit").live('click', function(){`.